# Run Mercure on production : 404 no found

Tags: mercure

I am contacting you because I can't get [mercure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html) to work in production.

The binary prebuild runs fine, but when I try to connect to the hub, I get a 404 no found.

Here is the command I run :

```
sudo MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6...' MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6...' SERVER_NAME=:3000 ./mercure run
```

the server launches without any problem apparently:

```
2022/02/15 17:38:09.919 INFO    using adjacent Caddyfile
2022/02/15 17:38:09.920 WARN    input is not formatted with 'caddy fmt' {"adapter": "caddyfile", "file": "Caddyfile", "line": 3}
2022/02/15 17:38:09.921 INFO    admin   admin endpoint started  {"address": "tcp/localhost:2019", "enforce_origin": false, "origins": ["[::1]:2019", "127.0.0.1:2019", "localhost:2019"]}
2022/02/15 17:38:09.922 INFO    tls.cache.maintenance   started background certificate maintenance      {"cache": "0xc0000cb7a0"}
2022/02/15 17:38:09.935 INFO    tls     cleaning storage unit   {"description": "FileStorage:/root/.local/share/caddy"}
2022/02/15 17:38:09.935 INFO    tls     finished cleaning storage units
2022/02/15 17:38:09.935 INFO    autosaved config (load with --resume flag)      {"file": "/root/.config/caddy/autosave.json"}
2022/02/15 17:38:09.935 INFO    serving initial configuration
```

my .env is configured as such:

```
###> symfony/mercure-bundle ###
MERCURE_URL=https://monsite.com/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=https://monsite.com/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6..."
###< symfony/mercure-bundle ###
```

My CaddyFile :

```
# Learn how to configure the Mercure.rocks Hub on https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config
{
        {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
}

{$SERVER_NAME:monsite.com}

log

route {
        encode zstd gzip

        mercure {
                # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
                transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
                # Publisher JWT key
                publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
                # Subscriber JWT key
                subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
                # Allow Subscribers
                anonymous
                # Extra directives
                {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
        }

        respond /healthz 200

        respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

When I try to access the hub with postman by typing the following command:

```
https://monsite.com/.well-known/mercure
```

I get a 404 no found.

I am under linux debian 10 with apache2. I don't understand what I did wrong. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT 21/02/2022**

Hi Mehmet, here is what I did:

In /etc/apache2/sites-available monsite.conf and monsite-le-ssl.conf :

```
ProxyPass /mercure-hub http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /mercure-hub http://localhost:8080/
```

In Caddyfile and Caddyfile.dev :

```
{
        {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
        auto_https off }

{$SERVER_NAME::8080}
```

Apparently the hub launches well, I have no error in the console:

```
debian@vps-...:/var/www/monsite/mercure$ sudo MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6I...' MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6I...' ./mercure run -config Caddyfile.dev
2022/02/21 13:31:20.672 INFO    using provided configuration    {"config_file": "Caddyfile.dev", "config_adapter": ""}
2022/02/21 13:31:20.675 WARN    input is not formatted with 'caddy fmt' {"adapter": "caddyfile", "file": "Caddyfile.dev", "line": 3}
2022/02/21 13:31:20.676 INFO    admin   admin endpoint started  {"address": "tcp/localhost:2019", "enforce_origin": false, "origins": ["localhost:2019", "[::1]:2019", "127.0.0.1:2019"]}
2022/02/21 13:31:20.676 INFO    tls.cache.maintenance   started background certificate maintenance      {"cache": "0xc0003fe700"}
2022/02/21 13:31:20.703 INFO    tls     cleaning storage unit   {"description": "FileStorage:/root/.local/share/caddy"}
2022/02/21 13:31:20.703 INFO    tls     finished cleaning storage units
2022/02/21 13:31:20.703 INFO    autosaved config (load with --resume flag)      {"file": "/root/.config/caddy/autosave.json"}
2022/02/21 13:31:20.704 INFO    serving initial configuration
```

Whether I run Caddyfile or Caddyfile.dev, when accessing https://monsite.com/mercure-hub, I get a 500 error.

Comment: you configurate apache conf?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: pls check https://monsite.com/healthz url. its return 200? Then  I can send my settings.

Comment: I got a 404 no found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I tried to figure out why it was returning a 500 error. I went to the apache logs, I had this error message:

> "No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO
> version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in
> the configuration using LoadModule"

So I installed the missing components:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

I also modified the proxy urls by adding a slash at the end of mercure-hub, otherwise I would get a 404 error:

```
 ProxyPass /mercure-hub/ http://localhost:8080/
 ProxyPassReverse /mercure-hub/ http://localhost:8080/
```

Restarted apache, and updated the Url in my .env :

```
MERCURE_URL=https://monsite.com/mercure-hub/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=https://monsite.com/mercure-hub/.well-known/mercure
```

And it works, thanks a lot !

Comment: Good job yinyang. That components are important. I thought you already installed it. Congrats for solution :)

Answer (score 0):

That is my apache settings. Maybe help to you.

open
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.com-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourdomain.com
        DirectoryIndex /index.php
        ServerName yourdomain.com

    #Settings for mercure
        ProxyPass      /mercure-hub     http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse /mercure-hub   http://localhost:8080


        <Directory /var/www/html/yourdomain.com >
                AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                FallbackResource /index.php
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/yourdomain.com >
                DirectoryIndex disabled
                FallbackResource disabled
        </Directory>


RewriteEngine on


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
#YOUR SSL PEM FİLES
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live …..
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live …..


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Your caddyfile option should like that

```
{
        {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
        auto_https off
}

{$SERVER_NAME::8080}#this parameter will run http://localhost:8080
```

Mercure command

```
MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='YOUR_KEY' MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='YOUR_KEY' ./mercure run -config Caddyfile
```

you can try with Caddyfile.dev for test.

```
MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='YOUR_KEY' MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='YOUR_KEY' ./mercure run -config Caddyfile.dev
```

after this settings your mercure will run yourdomain.com/mercure-hub

Comment: I followed what you said, but I get a 500 error when I try to access the mercure hub via https://monsite.com/mercure-hub. I'm updating my first post above to show you what I did.

Comment: Did you try with Caddyfile.dev? and you need restart apache

Comment: Yes I try Caddyfile.dev and restart apache. I updated my first post.

Comment: when I look at which ports are used, mercure uses port 8080 and 2019 :
sudo netstat -tunlp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2019          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      169530/./mercure    
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      169530/./mercure